# Boost.Python: Grab 'self' from member function

Tags: c++, python, boost

Class member functions in Python have to explicitly declare a `self` parameter which represents the class instance. Is there a way to get a hold of `self` from C++, by using Boost?

```
class FooBar
{
  public:
    void func() {
    }
};

// A wrapper for the above class
struct FooBar_W
    : public FooBar
{
    void func(boost::python::object self) {
        // Do smth with `self`
        FooBar::func();
    } 
};

BOOST_PYTHON_WRAPPER(module)
{
    class_<FooBar_W>("FooBar")
        .def("func", &FooBar_W::func)
     ;
}
```

---

**Edit:** Why I want `self`

I'm writing an event system for my game and I want the scripter to be able to define new types of events. I need a way to distinguish between different types of events. My Python code looks something like this:

```
class KeyboardEvent(Event): 
    pass

def onKeyPress(event):
    pass

# EventManager is defined in C++
em = EventManager()

# This is how I register a new callback function with the manager
# The `onKeyPress` function will now only be notified when an event
# of type `KeyboardEvent` occurs. (Notice that I passed the actual
# class object, and not an instance of it.)
em.addEventHandler(KeyboardEvent, onKeyPress)

# This is how I queue new events
# (This time I pass an instance of an event, not a type of event.)
em.queueEvent(KeyboardEvent())
```

The manager needs to figure out what type of event I just queued. I figured I should do something like `type(event).__name__` (but in C++, not in Python). This way I can determine the type and know which functions to notify of the event. I want to get `self` in C++ so I can access the `__name__` attribute of its type.

I could have the scripter manually edit a new field that holds the name of the type, but why? That information already exists (the `__name__` attribute) so why duplicate it, but more importantly, why bother the scripter with implementation details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's doable. The way to do it can be found in the link below; that page documents one way (the old way) to expose pure virtual functions. The example can be adapted to other needs, though.
> http://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/OverridableVirtualFunctions#Pure_Virtual_Functions

Answer (score 2):

it's an old question, but for those who are still looking for a reasonably simple solution:

Static function (non-member as well as member) receive a `const boost::python::object& self` as the first argument. So you can do the following:

```
class FooBar
{
  public:
    static void func(const boost::python::object self) {
        FooBar& thisref = boost::python::extract<FooBar&>(self)();
        // use self as well as thisref
    }
};

};

BOOST_PYTHON_WRAPPER(module)
{
    class_<FooBar>("FooBar")
        .def("func", &FooBar::func)
     ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`self` in python is `this` in C++.

You can think of the line `FooBar::func();` as translating to `static_cast<FooBar*>(this)->func()`

Comment: I want the Python object itself, not the C++ object.

Comment: Ah well I think Boost.Python's whole point is to hide the PyObject. I also didn't see your self parameter. Can you post your python client code? I still suspect you don't need to pass self. As in, I think you already have the python object in `this`